# Problems with pickle python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I recently made a program using an external document with pickle. But when it tries to load the file with pickle, I got this error (the file is already existing but it also fails when the file in't existing):

```
python3.6 check-graph_amazon.py

a
b
g
URL to follow www.amazon.com
Product to follow Pool_table
h
i
[' www.amazon.com', ' Pool_table', []]
p
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check-graph_amazon.py", line 17, in <module>
    tab_simple = pickle.load(doc_simple)
io.UnsupportedOperation: read

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check-graph_amazon.py", line 42, in <module>
    pickle.dump(tab_simple, 'simple_data.dat')
TypeError: file must have a 'write' attribute
```

Here is the code :

```
import pickle5 as pickle
#import os

try:
    print("a")
    with open('simple_data.dat', 'rb') as doc_simple:
        print("b")
        tab_simple = pickle.load(doc_simple)
        print("c")
        print(tab_simple)
        print("d")
        URL = tab_simple[0]
        produit_nom = tab_simple[1]
        tous_jours = tab_simple[2]
        print("f")

except :
    print("g")
    URL = str(input("URL to follow"))
    produit_nom = str(input("Product to follow"))

    with open('simple_data.dat', 'wb+') as doc_simple:
        print("h")
        #os.system('chmod +x simple_data.dat') 
        tab_simple = []
        tab_simple.append(URL)
        tab_simple.append(produit_nom)
        tab_simple.append([])
        print(tab_simple)
        print("c'est le 2")
        print("p")
        pickle.dump(tab_simple, 'simple_data.dat')
        print("q")
```

The prints are here to show which lines are executed. The `os.system` is here to allow writing on the file but the error is persisting.

I don't understand why it's said that the document doesn't have a write attribute because I opened it in writing mode. And I neither understand the first error where it can't load the file.

If it can help you the goal of this script is to initialise the program, with a `try`. It tries to open the document in reading mode in the `try` part and then set variables. If the document doesn't exist (because the program is lauched for the first time) it goes in the `except` part and create the document, before writing informations on it.

I hope you will have any clue, including changing the architecture of the code if you have a better way to make an initialisation for the 1st time the program is launched.

Thanks you in advance and sorry if the code isn't well formated, I'm a beginner with this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [the docs for `pickle.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

> ```
> pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True)
> ```
>
> Write a pickled representation of `obj` to the *open file object* `file`. ...
>
> ...
>
> The `file` argument must have a `write()` method that accepts a single bytes argument. It can thus be an on-disk file opened for binary writing, an `io.BytesIO` instance, or any other custom object that meets this interface.

So, you should pass to this function a *file object*, not a file name, like this:

```
with open("simple_data.dat", "wb"): as File:
   pickle.dump(tab_simple, File)
```

Yeah, in your case the file has already been opened, so you should write to `doc_simple`.

Comment: This. OP already opens the file but uses the file name instead of the file handler `doc_simple`